# Is there's another function to optimize this query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I want to use a function that returns for me the same result in one line is that's possible??

```
MIN(
    CASE 
       WHEN (data.pro LIKE '1 %'   )  THEN 1
       WHEN (data.pro LIKE '2 %'   )  THEN 2
       WHEN (data.pro LIKE '3 %'   )  THEN 3
       WHEN (data.pro LIKE '4 %'   )  THEN 4
       WHEN (data.pro LIKE '5 %'   )  THEN 5
       WHEN (data.pro LIKE '6 %'   )  THEN 6
    END) as products
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to match '1 ' to '6 ' at the beginning of the string:

```
data.pro rlike '^([1-6] )'
```

Now put this in a `CASE`:

```
case when data.pro rlike '^([1-6] )' 
     then cast(substring(data.pro from 1 for 1) as unsigned)
end
```

See the result in MySQL 5.5 on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da5f4/1).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on data.pro:

```
select substring(min(data.pro),1,1) from products where substring(data.pro,1,2) in ('1 ','2 ','3 ','4 ','5 ','6 ') order by data.pro;
```

Instead of a select case on each record of your products, take the minimum-record between for your range from 1-6 (starts with that number anyway). If there is a good index for that, only 1 record will be examined and received.

A good practice is to test statements with 'explain ...', to see how many records get examined.